# Finding shortest sequence of vertices in directed weighted graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Let's say I have vertices `u` and `v` and some number `n`.

How can I calculate the length (sum of weights of edges) of the shortest sequence of vertices where there is an edge between every two vertices?

For example:

```
(u, e_1, u_2, e_2, ..., e_n, v)
```

The sequence is starting with vertex `u`, ending with vertex `v` and it has `n` edges.

Comment: Are repetitions allowed ?

Comment: @krjampani yes, they are

Answer (score 3):

Since repetitions are allowed this can be solved in polynomial time by a slight variation of the Bellman-Ford algorithm. Let OPT(v,i) denote the optimal cost to reach v using i edges and let w(x,y) denote the weight between vertices x and y. Then we have the following recurrence:

OPT(v, i+1) = min { OPT(u, i) + w(u,v) }, over all edges (u,v).

This can be solved in a bottom up fashion in O(nm), where m is the number of edges. Here's the pseudocode.

```
function computeShortestPath (u, v, n):
    foreach q in vertices:
        OPT[q][0] = inf;
    OPT[u][0] = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++):
        foreach q in vertices:
            OPT[q][i] = inf;
        foreach (p,q) in edges:
            OPT[q][i] = min(OPT[q][i], OPT[p][i-1] + w[p][q]);
    return OPT[v][n];
```

Note that if repetitions aren't allowed the problem is a generalization of the Hamiltonian path problem which is NP-Hard.

Comment: What does `w(u, v)` mean? Weight of the edges between `u` and `v`?

Comment: Yes, it represents the weight.

Comment: How do I know that I used exactly `n` edges (where `n` is number I was given)?

Comment: By definition, OPT(v, k) represents the optimal cost of the path from u to v using exactly k edges. So OPT(v, n) gives you the solution.

Comment: So basically I am starting from the vertex `v` and want to get to `u`, then I will do it in for loop: `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) do OPT(v, i + 1) = min {OPT(x, i) + w(x + v)}` over all edges `(u, x)` where `x` is vertex between vertices `u` and `v`?

Then how method OPT will look?

Comment: You have to compute OPT(q, i) for all vertices q and all numbers i until n. Added pseudocode for clarification.

Comment: One last question, in your pseudocode you have `return OPT(v, n)` but where does method start? I am little bit confused what is inner part of method `OPT()`. Also you are writing polynomial time and then `O(nm)`

Comment: OPT(v, n) would translate into an array in a real implementation. Updated the code to make it more clear and also fixed an error in the initialization. n*m is a polynomial function. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by Dynamic Programming. We first solve the problem with "n-1" for each node with an outgoing edge to "v" starting from node "u" then the solution is `min(sum(sol(u,r),weight(r,v)))`
This algorithm is of O(n|vertices|).